# jsTree does not retain node selection after Refresh Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jstree, event-binding

The jsTree when refreshed does not retain the previous selected Node.
When the jsTree is opened and a node is the selected, then on refresh, the jsTree is closed.
[This is the jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/10/)

I had tried with event binding but does not seem to work. Please let me know of a work around.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree();
});

function refresh(){
   $("#jstree").jstree("refresh");
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve..its natural if you will refresh jstree then it will close..what is the problem then????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edit your fiddle. Ist this what you want??

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/15/)

```
$(function () {
$('#jstree').jstree({plugins: ["state"]});
});


function refresh(){
$("#jstree").jstree("refresh");
}
```